# Minimum connection time in Riyadh for international flights?

Tags: connecting-flights, airport-terminals, wizz-air, self-transfer, riyadh

I’m travelling this summer with many layovers and one of them is in Riiyadh for 1h20. I’ll be arriving from Rome (Wizz Air) and will be departing to Mumbai (Flynas). Probably the connection will be between Terminals 1-3 or 2-3. Is it enough time to arrive to the next flight or should I change the schedule?
(I’m not bringing checked baggage so I don’t need to pick it up, just a backpack with me)

Comment: For completeness, will you need to clear immigration, collect & re-check baggage? Flynas bag drop closes 60mins before departure, if you’re self-transferring you really should allow at least 3 hours https://www.flynas.com/en/help/online-checkin

Comment: Sorry, I’m not bringing any facturing luggage, just a backpack

Answer (score 5):

> Is it enough time to arrive to the next flight

No

> or should I change the schedule?

Yes.

This is a self connection as Whizz Air does NOT offer connecting flights or baggage transfer. For a self transfer you need to

1. Get off the plane
2. Clear immigration (and you need documentation to enter Saudi Arabia)
3. Collect your checked luggage (if you have any)
4. Clear customs
5. Exit to the landside arrival terminal
6. Transfer to your departure terminal
7. Go to check in counter and/or bag drop off (depends if you have luggage and if online checkin is available). Check in, drop bags, get boarding pass. You must arrive there before the check-in and/or bag drop cutoff time.
8. Go through security again
9. Head to your departure gate
10. Arrive before gate closing time

The chances of making this connection are very low. If you miss it, you are a "no-show" for your second ticket, Flynas has no obligation to you whatsoever and you may have to buy a very expensive same-day ticket on the spot.

Personally I don't do self connections under 3 hours (best case) and significantly more depending on various risk factors.

Wizz Air doesn't operate connecting flights. From their T&C

> Wizz Air does not operate connecting flights and cannot facilitate the transfer of passengers or their baggage to other flights (whether operated by Wizz Air or other carriers). For this reason, we cannot accept liability for any missed onward flights.

Comment: (+1) The OP mentions that their trip includes many layovers; some may be (much) longer than the 1hr 20 in the question however worth noting that in general the points in this answer will apply to all self-transfers in the OP’s itinerary.